# How to change File modification date without using System.IO

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I am writing code in Unity and I want to change file modification date. For that purpouse I am using `File.SetLastWriteTime` method. It works fine but on some android versions it simply does not work and gives me an erorr `IOException: Invalid parameter`. I googled tha and it seems to be some unresolved bug as number of people reported the same.

My question here is: is there another library or different way I can change last modification date using C#?

edit: I need to preserve original modification date. The file is being downloaded from Amazon S3 but the modification date is set to the exact moment that the file is being saved on the device. This is why after I downloaded it I tried to do `File.SetLastWriteTime(file, original_date)`

Answer (score 1):

Check below code:

```
string fileName = @"E:\test.txt";
File.SetLastWriteTime(fileName, DateTime.Now);
```

[image: Before run the code]

[image: After run the code]

I took snapshot for both the modified date. After and before run the code. You will check the given path again.

Comment: This is true, please read my post: it works on windows without problem. Unfortunately this method does not work on some android devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing for some arbitrary files when using SetLastWriteTime via mono on a Synology NAS - some files failed with "Invalid parameter" IOExceptions.

After digging into it a bit, I found it was a permissions/ownership issue - running the same thing with sudo worked.